# Using circles to determine shortest path in tsp

Tags: traveling-salesman

**New to tsp and christofide algorithm pls help**

What if instead of using a spanning tree as described in christofide algorithm we use two or more intersecting circles of the input points to determine shortest distance?
Suppose we have 5 points, we draw 5 circles around them of same radius as per the choice of the user and then determine the shortest path between centres of two intersecting circles. The more the circle intersect the more their centres are closer to each other. Will it work or its just stupid

Comment: It seems like you want to devise an approximation algorithm for Euclidean TSP. Is that right? Or do you just want a heuristic?  For an algorithm to make sense it needs to be formally defined. As it's stated now, it's not formal enough to reason about. I guess you want to parameterize on the number of points per circle, or maybe better than circle is "cluster". You could run $k$-means to find $k$ clusters, but then you have to solve TSP on those.

Comment: My question is: a) how do you solve a circle and b) what do you do between circles?